# Sliding Door Frame Slightly Bent Towards Center

Tags: door-frame

I recently moved into a new house and have noticed that the sliding door frame slightly bends toward the inside of the house.

If you open the door and stand perpendicular to the door in the door opening, the edges of the frame (where the door slides into) look similar to 2 right parenthesis.
`))`

Sliding the door in, it kind of gets stuck on the inside bend, but it is easy to push through it
`)|)`

I will share real picture below. The parenthesis just give an exaggerated idea of the shape because it is hard to see in the picture/video.

Is this a structural problem? Is there a way to straighten it out? Can I just leave it as-is?

Video: https://youtu.be/-oW9U2vsUl8

Picture:
[image]

Comment: Many new contractors lock in the frame work with no or not enough space on the header. When the wood drys and shrinks the frames buckle. This may be the case, today's wood needs close to a 1/2" top clearance in my opinion.

Comment: Open the door and check the mounting screws on that frame piece (jamb). Unscrew any that are not on the very top and bottom and see if there is flex to the jamb. Sometimes these guys fail to shim the jambs and then overdrive the screws, causing the jamb to bow. But @Ed Beal describes a more likely scenario, not enough clearance provided combined with framing movement. Are they vinyl? Vinyl expands a whole lot with temperature changes.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll check it out tomorrow or this weekend.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Yeah it's vinyl.

Comment: Could be the vinyl expanding without room for it! +1 for nice linked video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the suggestions in the comment section are valid. If adjusting the jamb screws doesn't solve the problem, you will need to remove the trim to inspect how the door frame was shimmed. A gap in the location you showed indicates a lack of back support or over tightened screws. You may need to add shims to eliminate the gap.

Comment: Thanks shirlock. The jam screws didn't fix it. I might get to removing trim and adding shims someday.